# Trailing slash automatically added in url

Tags: .htaccess, url, web, routes

When I type a url, a trailing slash is automatically added.

Why?

For example, I type:

`example.com/path`

and it becomes:

`example.com/path/`

---

My .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    AddType 'text/css; charset=UTF-8' css

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Yes. Actually it is the public/ directory in which resides the index.php that does all the routing

Comment: If your URL points to a directory then Apache automatically adds a trailing slash for security reasons.

Comment: @anubhava Thx. Better create a proper answer to this question (rather that a comment) and add some quote or source.

Comment: ok sure, have added an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your URL points to a directory then Apache's `mod_dir` module automatically adds a trailing slash for security reasons.

[Apache `mod_dir` reference on directory slash](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash)

Please note that you can change this behavior by placing this directive:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

However keep in mind this **security warning**.

**Security Warning**

> Turning off the trailing slash redirect may result in an information disclosure. Consider a situation where `mod_autoindex` is active (`Options +Indexes`) and `DirectoryIndex` is set to a valid resource (say, `index.html`) and there's no other special handler defined for that URL. In this case a request with a trailing slash would show the `index.html` file. **But a request without trailing slash would list the directory contents.**

Answer (score 0):

To remove a trailing slash you can just use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: where do I put his in my .htaccess?